# XSLT Error cause

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i've the below xslt.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="index/title"/>
                </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="er:#css" type="text/css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="index">
        <div class="index">
            <xsl:variable name="num">
                <xsl:number level="any" format="01"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <a name="BVI_IDX_{$num}"/>
            <div class="index-title">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="index/title/@text()"/>
            </div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--<xsl:template match="index">
        <div class="index">
            <div class="index-title">
                <xsl:value-of select="index/title/@text()"/>
            </div>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>-->
    <xsl:template match="indexdiv">
        <div class="indexdiv">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="indexdiv/title">

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="indexentry">
        <div class="indexentry">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="primaryie">
        <div class="primaryie">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="content-style"/>
            <xsl:if test="contains(current()/text(), '.')">
                <xsl:variable name="numberString" select="substring(current()/text(), string-length(substring-before(current()/text(),'.'))-1)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                    <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="$numberString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="secondaryie">
        <xsl:variable name="textAll">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="textOnly">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($textAll,'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll,1,string-length(substring-before($textAll,'.'))-1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="textAll1">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="numbersOnly">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($textAll1,'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll1,string-length($textOnly))"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="secondaryie">
            <xsl:value-of select="$textOnly"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="$numbersOnly"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="current()/content-style/node()">
                <xsl:for-each select="current()/content-style">
                    <xsl:call-template name="content-style"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tertiaryie">
        <xsl:variable name="tertClassType">
            <xsl:value-of select="@level"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tertClassTypName">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('tertiaryie-', $tertClassType)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="textAll">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="textOnly">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($textAll,'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll,1,string-length(substring-before($textAll,'.'))-1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="textAll1">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="numbersOnly">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($textAll1,'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll1,string-length($textOnly))"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="{$tertClassTypName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$textOnly"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="$numbersOnly"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content-style" name="content-style">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <!--        <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="matches(.,".*\d\.\d+-\d\.\d+.*")">
</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
-->
<xsl:variable name="textAll">
                <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($textAll, '.')">

            <xsl:variable name="textOnly">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($textAll,'.')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll,1,string-length(substring-before($textAll,'.'))-1)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="numbersOnly">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($textAll,'.')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($textAll,string-length($textOnly))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$textOnly"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                    <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="$numbersOnly"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

                </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                         <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>


        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="numbersToLink">
        <xsl:param name="numbersString"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numbersString, ',')">
                <xsl:call-template name="splitByComma">
                    <xsl:with-param name="numString" select="$numbersString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numbersString, '-')">
                <xsl:call-template name="splitByHyphen">
                    <xsl:with-param name="numString" select="$numbersString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="5 >= string-length(normalize-space($numbersString))">
                <xsl:variable name="x">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($numbersString,'.')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="y">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($numbersString,'.'))"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!--  er:#BVI_CH_07/P7-251-->
                <xsl:variable name="conca">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#BVI_CH_0',$y,'/P',$y,'-',$x)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <a href="{$conca}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$numbersString"/>
                </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="splitByComma">
        <xsl:param name="numString"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($numString,','), '-')">
                <xsl:call-template name="splitByHyphen">
                    <xsl:with-param name="numString" select="$numString"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numString,',')">
                <xsl:variable name="abc">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($numString,'.'))"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="def">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($numString,'.'),',') "/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="conct">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#BVI_CH_0',$abc,'/P',$abc,'-',$def)"/>
                    <!--"concat(concat('er:#BVI_CH_0',,'/P',$y,'-',$x)"/-->
                </xsl:variable>
                <a href="{$conct}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($numString,',')"/>
                </a>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($numString,','), '.')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                        <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="normalize-space(substring-after($numString,','))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="splitByHyphen">
        <xsl:param name="numString"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numString,'-')">
                <xsl:variable name="abc">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($numString,'.'))"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="def">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($numString,'.'),'-') "/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="conct">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#BVI_CH_0',$abc,'/P',$abc,'-',$def)"/>
                    <!--"concat(concat('er:#BVI_CH_0',,'/P',$y,'-',$x)"/-->
                </xsl:variable>
                <a href="{$conct}">
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($numString,'-')"/>-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($numString,'-')"/>
                </a>
                <xsl:text>&#x2013;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($numString,'-'), '.')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="numbersToLink">
                        <xsl:with-param name="numbersString" select="normalize-space(substring-after($numString,'-'))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i'm using this with my xml sheet in Altova XMLSpy. it is not giving any error. but when i'm using with other xml editors(oxygen and liquid xml) it is throwing the below error.

```
    Severity: error
Description: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("", "") 
Start location: 56:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPTY0004
```

please let me know why is this happening and how do i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which line exactly causes that error? And how does the XML input look?

Altova is known to strip white space text nodes, if you want the same behavior with Saxon then add

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` element. That might fix it, assuming that the error is caused by an attempt to select text contents with `text()` which then includes white space text nodes with Saxon which are stripped with Altova.

But generally I would avoid using `text()` and simply select the string contents with `.` (and relying on atomization of the function argument when passed to functions like `contains`) or do `string(.)` explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Line 56 is this:

The error means that the current node (a primaryie element) has more than one text node child. Perhaps some of these are whitespace text nodes - Altova uses the Microsoft XML parser, which strips whitespace text nodes by default. It's hard to know what you should replace this with, without knowing your application, but it should perhaps be `test="contains(., '.')"`.

Incidentally, there's some bad code in your stylesheet. This:

```
<xsl:value-of select="index/title/@text()"/>
```

selects all the text nodes on the attribute axis. There will never be any text nodes on the attribute axis, though it's legal to ask for them. Your stylesheet also makes frequent use of the construct

```
<xsl:variable name="tertClassType">
     <xsl:value-of select="@level"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

which is a terribly inefficient and verbose way of getting the same effect as

```
<xsl:variable name="tertClassType" select="@level"/>
```